# Setting effects variables in XNA

Tags: xna, effects

I am currently reading a book named "3D Graphics with XNA Game Studio 4.0" by Sean James and have some questions to ask :

If i create a effect parameter named lets say SpecularPower and have in my effect a variable named SpecularPower , if i do something like

> effect.Parameters["SpecularPower"].SetValue(3)

That wil change the SpecularPower variable in my effect ?

And a second question, not regarding the book : 
If i have a spaceship and i've created a "boost" functionality that speeds up my spaceship, what effects should i implement to create the impresion oh high speed ? I was thinking of making everything except my spaceship blurry but i think there would be something missing . Any ideas ?

Regards,
Alex Badescu

Comment: Probably best to separate out your two questions into two different questions.

Comment: Agreed; you should ask the second question separately as it is entirely different rather than a kind of subquestion. See here: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/385/how-should-multiple-questions-in-one-be-handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parameters` is an [EffectParameterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.effectparametercollection_members.aspx), which is indexable by string and integer. Indexing it by string returns an [EffectParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.effectparameter.aspx) for the named parameter, which can be used to assign values to that parameter, as illustrated in the link documentation.

In short, the answer to your first question is "yes."